# Grep and What If 75

Tags: macos, command-line, grep, dictionary

I'm trying to run the command from [What if 75](http://what-if.xkcd.com/75/):

```
 cat wordlist.txt | perl -pe 's/^(.*)$/\L$& \U$&/g' | tr 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' '2223334445556667777888999' | grep -P "(.)\1\1\1\1\1"
```

I replaced `wordlist.txt` with `/usr/share/dict/words` because I'm on OS X.

When I run the command, all I get is `grep`'s usage message. If I run the command with the grep portion removed, it seems to be doing what should.

How can I edit the command to make it work correctly?

**EDIT:** I replaced `grep -P` with `egrep` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from xkcd uses [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) (many Linux distros), not [BSD grep](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep) (Mac OS X).

*GNU grep* has some features *BSD grep* doesn't, e.g. [Perl-compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE).

The pattern in your example, `(.)\1\1\1\1\1`, actually works for both PCRE and *Extended Regular Expressions* (ERE); if you modify the syntax slightly, you can even use *Basic Regular Expressions* (BRE):

```
grep -P "(.)\1\1\1\1\1"
grep -E "(.)\1\1\1\1\1"
grep "\(.\)\1\1\1\1\1"
```

all work as expected, as long as the feature is available. The latter two will work on OS X or any other implementation without GNU extensions.

For a formal definition of BRE and ERE, click [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

For the differences between BRE, ERE and PCRE, consult [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y).